# Json_Array with Group_Concat does not give a single array of string

Tags: mysql

We have 2 tables. Question which has a `question` and Answers which has possible `answer`'s for that question.

I want to collect all the questions such that all the answers for a given question appear in form of array.

```
select Answers.question_Id as questionId, 
       group_concat(json_array(Answers.answer)) as answers
      from Question 
      inner join Answers 
      on Question.id = Answers.question_Id 
      group by questionId
```

When I tried the above query I get the following output :

```
------------------------------------
questionId | answers
--------------------------
1          | ["1"],["2"],["3"],["4"]
------------------------------------
```

So I tried the following query :

```
select Answers.question_Id as questionId, 
          json_array(group_concat(Answers.answer)) as answers
          from Question 
          inner join Answers 
          on Question.id = Answers.question_Id 
          group by questionId
```

I get following output :

---

```
questionId | answers
--------------------------
1          | ["1,2,3,4"]
--------------------------
```

What I am looking for is `['1', '2', '3', '4']`

Any suggestions what would be a good way. 
I also tried using only group_concat but it separates the output by comma 
and there are high chances that the answer will have comma in it.
I was looking for a simple solution.

MySQL version : 5.7.19

Comment: Why do you need JSON output?

Comment: actually I need it in form of array

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL `5.7.22` or later, you may use the [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) function:

```
SELECT
    a.question_Id AS questionId, 
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(a.answer) AS answers
FROM Question q
INNER JOIN Answers a
    ON q.id = q.question_Id 
GROUP BY
    a.question_Id
```

Comment: We are using MYSQL 5.7.19

Comment: Then you may be somewhat out of luck.  There might be a UDF which can do this.  Are you using MySQL with an app language, such as Java or C#?  They can easily handle your requirement.